# SharePoint Online - Adding Group Manager to TermStore Group using Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365, term-store

Is it possible to add Group Manager, Contributor to a TermStore Group in SharePoint Online using PowerShell?
Something like:

```
$termGroup.AddGroupManager(“GroupName”)   
$termGroup.AddContributor(“GroupName”) 
$termStore.CommitAll()
```

I tried this but looks like AddGroupManager doesnt exist for SharePoint Online

Answer (score 1):

- I think you'd use SharePoint Online Management Shell insteed of Power Shell.
  Link to download : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35588
- I have found this post that could help you to manage term store and groups using PowerShell online [here](https://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2014/11/12/exporting-taxonomy-from-sharepoint-using-powershell/)

Hope this could help!